# Triggering CSS animation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="animation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="box box-anim-start box-anim-end"></div>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see there are two stylesheets linked to this page.

**StyleSheet code**

```
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**animation code**

```
.box-anim-start {
}

.box-anim-end {
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-delay: 5s;
}
```

And here's the JavaScript code

```
var box = $(".box").eq(0);
var sheet = document.styleSheets[1];
var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;
var rule0 = rules[0];
rule0.style.transform = "translateX(100px)";
var rule1 = rules[1];
rule1.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
```

What I wanted was an animation upon opening this page. And, since the delay is mentioned in css, i thought that would work. But it didn't. Could you explain why?

Comment: why do you modify the style sheet rules via JS instead of setting the `box-anim-end` class via JS?

Comment: @JohannesJander this is just an example, isn't it? the value 100px is dynamic in my real program.

Comment: even if i add classes via addclass, the same happens.

Comment: But the animation is triggered by setting the CSS class. Did you even try with `translateX` in the CSS and setting the class via JS?

Answer (score 2):

It's makes a lot more sense to define your CSS animation in your CSS using keyframes, you can then call it in by adding a class to your box once the page has loaded.

So initially remove the `.box-anim-start` class

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Then define the animation using keyframes:

```
@keyframes slide {
  0%{ 
    transform: translate(0, 0)
  }
  100% { 
    transform: translate(100px, 0)
  }
}
```

Then call the animation within `.box-anim-start`

```
.box-anim-start {
  animation: slide ease-in 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.box{
  transition: 2s ease-in;
}
```

And finally add the class once the page has loaded using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function){
   $('.box').addClass('.box-anim-start');
});
```

Comment: most likely but I've never done that before, what do you want to change? it's easier to create multiple keyframes animations and then you call them in by adding / removing different animations classes

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the stylesheet.

In Chrome, for instance, your line:

```
 var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;
```

is wrong because rules is null.  This happens because you need to change the index to

var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];  // instead of 1 in my case

But consider to put a delay between the two transition.

Instead, if you want simply use the js with your styles you can do:

```js
$(function () {
  $('div.box').css('transform', 'translateX(100px)').delay(3000).queue(function (next) {
    $(this).css('transform', 'translateX(0px)');
    next();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.box-anim-start {
}

.box-anim-end {
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div class="box box-anim-start box-anim-end"></div>
```